# Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_121: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am building a deep colorization model using the CIFAR dataset. I have converted the rgb images into lab for the same. Now for that, the input X_train needs only the grayscale part of lab while the output labels are the coloured part. X_train dimensions = [50000,32,32] and Y_train = [50000,32,32,2]. I am getting this dimensional error for some reason while training the dataset.

```
model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',input_shape = (50000,32,32,1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))

    model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    #model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    #model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same'))
    #model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))

    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')
    model_info = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, 
                           batch_size=128, epochs=200)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove 50000 from input shape. As you are already specifying batch size in model.fit().

Batch size is considered in the dimension. In your case it would become
(128,50000,32,32,1).

And surely you would not be training on 50000 at once.

Comment: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_10_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (50000, 32, 32) gives this error when input_shape = (32,32,1)